# Bootstrap 3 - Image vertically align in middle left in desktop, and centered in mobile/tablet view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm not a hard CSS coder, i would need help. In this project i've had a logo and don't know how to center back the image when the collapse md-3 section.

When the website are in desktop view col-md-3; i want to vertically align the image "Left Middle" and when it resize to col-sm-3 or col-xs-3 be positioned into center middle;.

Here are the URL;
http://test2.supraz2000.com/

The section are...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class"row">
        <!-- 1rst Row of 3 Top Header section -->    
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="color:#FFFFFF; height:125px; padding-top:24px;">
            <a target="_blank" href="/"><img alt="SUPRAZ2000 INC." src="<%=get_skinurl()%>img/logo-supraz-fr.png"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- 2nd Row of 3 Top Header section -->
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center" style="color:#FFFFFF; height:125px; padding-top:18px; text-align:center;">
            <span style="text-align:center !important;"><a href="<%=get_StoreURL()%>shoppingcart.wws"><%= Minicart("cartinfo-total.wws") %></a></span>
            <span style="padding-right:5px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>&nbsp;<a href="<%=get_StoreURL()%>customerdashboard.wws" style="color:#F3CE62;">Mon compte</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="padding-right:5px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;<a href="<%=get_StoreURL()%>customerorderhistory.wws" style="color:#F3CE62;">Retracez une commande</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="padding-right:5px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>&nbsp;<a href="<%=get_StoreURL()%>validateshoppingcart.wws" style="color:#F3CE62;">Mon panier</a>
        </div>

        <!-- 3rd Row of 3 Top Header section -->
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="height:125px; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; padding-top:16px;">
            <div class="text-center">
                <table width="250" height="90" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-image:url(img/telephone_tollfree-fr.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                <div id="tel" style="font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:24px; color:#000000; letter-spacing:-1px; text-shadow:1px 1px #FFFFFF; padding-left:73px;"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finaly found my answer by myself.

I need to reset CSS code regarding to "@media and" for screen resolution and realign the class according where the logo need to be positioned.